# Configure consul health check to spring boot actuator '/health'

Tags: spring, spring-boot, microservices, consul, spring-boot-actuator

For a microservice that I have been working on, I created a custom health check class extending AbstractHealthIndicator and able to get the output in

```
http://localhost:8080/actuator/health
```

But when I register the service with consul, the health check status is failing.

Tried to configure the actuator url with consul health check as`spring.cloud.consul.discovery.health-check-url= http://localhost:8080/actuator/health` in bootstrap. But it is still failing with error `Get http://localhost:8566/actuator/health: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8566: connect: connection refused`

If I try with `health-check-path: /actuator/health`, it is not taking this path at all and defaulting to `http://QINDW062.it.local:8566/my-health-check`.

Any suggestions?

Edit:

Comment: Is your consul client running on the same machine as your app? Can you provide your service definition (https://www.consul.io/docs/agent/services.html#service-definition) ?

Comment: consul is running through docker. Configured the ip in bootstrap and my app is able to read values from it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a property in your configurations file (application.yml for example) pointing to your health check endpoint:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    consul:
      discovery:
        healthCheckPath: /actuator/health
```

You can also decide the time interval for the health check (how often Consul will call the health check) with the following property:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    consul:
      discovery:
        healthCheckInterval: 20s
```